# Function $f$ that "magnifies" the correlation between $f(X_1, \dots, X_n)$ and $f(Y_1, \dots, Y_n)$, if $X_i=Y_i$ for some $i$.

Tags: probability, random-variables

I am trying to phrase properly (and either gain insight or answer) a question on "increasing correlation" between two r.v.'s obtained by combining either two independent families of random variables, or two families independent except for one of their element.

I came up with the following formulation, but am stuck -- i.e., I don't even know if it is trivial, too open-ended, or nonsensical.

Assume $Z\sim D$, $X_1,\dots, X_n\sim D$ and $Y_1,\dots, Y_n\sim D$ are independent random variables (i.e., the X_i's are independent of the $Y_j$'s and of $Z$, but the $X_i$'s (resp. $Y_j$'s) need not be independent "among themselves"), distributed on domain $\{0,1,\dots,m\}$. Are there a distribution $D$ and a function $f$ such that the following holds:

- $f(X_1,\dots,X_n)$ and $f(Y_1,\dots,Y_n)$ are independent
- for any fixed $1\leq i\leq n$, we have
  $$d_{\rm TV}( f(X_1,\dots, X_{i-1},Z,X_{i+1},\dots,X_n), f(X_1,\dots, X_{i-1},X_i,X_{i+1},\dots,X_n) ) = 0$$ but $$d_{\rm TV}(f(Y_1,\dots, Y_{i-1},Z,Y_{i+1},\dots,Y_n),f(Y_1,\dots, Y_{i-1},Y_i,Y_{i+1},\dots,Y_n)) \geq 1/10.$$

Put differently, can a correlation in only one variable of $f$ make the resulting random variables very different?

Comment: Let $f(Z)$, $f(X_i)$ be constant while $f(Y_i)$ is not - where all function are such that the rest of the variables are held constant. For example $Z=X_i=C_1$ while $X_i\ne Y_i=C_2t$ and $f(X_i)\ne f(Y_i)$.

Comment: @A.S. I am not certain to understand -- here, $f$ is supposed to be the same all throughout. (Is that the case in your comment?)

Comment: It is. It is constant on range of $X_i$ and $Z$ and a different value on range of $Y_i$.

Comment: I see ((modulo the fact that $f$ is a $n$-variate function). I guess it's once more due to my bad formulation of what I want to achieve -- I'll edit my question to add a more stringent condition on the distributions.

Comment: For the first $d_{TV}=0$ equality to hold, you need either $D$ be a denegerate distribution (one value) or $f$ to be constant in $i$th coordinate - otherwise independence of $Z$ an $X_i$ will pull distributions apart. In both cases, the second inequality is impossible. We need another iteration ;).

Comment: Why so? If $X_i$ and $Z$ are i.i.d., then the distributions will be the same -- and their total variation be zero. (Here, $d_{\rm TV}$ is the total variation/half $L_1$ distance between the distributions of the r.v.'s). Take $f$ to be the sum, for instance, and $D$ to be a Bernoulli $1/2$ distribution. Then we do obtain the first total variation equality (but not the scond condition, alas), since both $f(\dots,Z,\dots)$ and $f(\dots,X_i,\dots)$ will be Binomials $(n,1/2)$.

Comment: (although the need for a second iteration may very well end up being required -- for another reason :) )

Comment: My bad. You are right. But if they are all i.i.d., switching $X$'s  to $Y$'s (from $(1)$ to $(2)$) doesn't change a thing as arguments are are jointly distributed in the same way.

Comment: And here comes the second iteration... Thank you ! (I need independence of $(X_i)$, $(Y_i)$ and $Z$ between themselves, but not of the $X_i$'s between themselves... does that make sense?

Comment: It does, but in the current installment you have basically answered the question. Let $n=2$, $i=1$, let $D=B(1,p)$, $f$ is a sum, $X_i$'s are independent and let $Y_1=Y_2$. $2B(1,p)$ is well-separated from $B(2,p)$

Comment: Oh -- the issue is that I don't get to choose $n$ (typically, insanely big values, $n\to\infty$)

Comment: I don't see how large $n$ changes anything. You can fill the above example with independent copies or make $f$ insensitive to all other coordinates.

Comment: @A.S. (I feel a bit awkward given the level of open-endedness of the question): I have the feeling that the condition in the second bullet "for any $i$") prevented that (?)

Comment: For *any* $n$, you can make all $X_i$ independent (to ensure the first $d_{TV}$ equality for all $i$) and all $Y_i$ equal to each other (to ensure the second inequality for all $i$).

Comment: @A.S.Thanks! While this is not answering the question I was *trying* to ask (and failed to), but does answer the one I *did* ask.. If you post an answer, I'll accept it.